# Javascript Remove Braces

Tags: javascript

I have the string "{Street Name}, {City}, {Country}" and want to remove all braces.
The result should be "Street Name, City, County".  How do I do that?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If you want to remove all occurrences of `{` and `}` whether or not they are matched pairs, you can do it like this:

```
var str = "{Street Name}, {City}, {Country}";
str = str.replace(/[{}]/g, "");
```

Answer (score 1):

The character class `[{}]` will find all curly braces

```
var address = "{Street Name}, {City}, {Country}";
address = address.replace( /[{}]/g, '' );
console.log( address ) // Street Name, City, Country
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str = str.replace(/[{}]/g,"");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this javascript simple code in your respective function to remove braces :

```
        var str = '{Street Name}, {City}, {Country}';
        str = str.replace(/{/g, '').replace(/}/g, '');
```