# Replace { and }

Tags: javascript

There is a problem.
After JSON.stringify I have a string:

```
value.value_new = {"apiunits":{"amount":"0"},"total":{"requests":"10","results":"10"},"project":{"projects":"1"}};
```

I want to replace { and }, and I try to do it this way:

```
value.value_new = value.value_new.replace("/[{}]/g", " ");
```

or

```
value.value_new = value.value_new.replace("/{/g", " ");
value.value_new = value.value_new.replace("/}/g", " ");
```

But it doesn't work. Why?

Comment: what would you later do with it?

Comment: *There is a problem. After JSON.stringify I have a string*! Funniest thing I've read all day! But back to being serious, why would you wanna remove them?

Comment: i need to display it without brackets.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8307039/javascript-remove-braces

Comment: i saw this example. but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`value.value_new` is not a string, so you can't use the function `replace` on it.

If you just need this string without the brackets, you can use this method :

```
var value = {};
value.value_new = '{"apiunits":{"amount":"0"},"total":{"requests":"10","results":"10"},"project":{"projects":"1"}}';

String.prototype.replaceAll = function(str1, str2, ignore) 
{
    return this.replace(new RegExp(str1.replace(/([\/\,\!\\\^\$\{\}\[\]\(\)\.\*\+\?\|\<\>\-\&])/g,"\\$&"),(ignore?"gi":"g")),(typeof(str2)=="string")?str2.replace(/\$/g,"$$$$"):str2);
} 

value.value_new = value.value_new.replaceAll("{", '');
value.value_new = value.value_new.replaceAll("}", '');


console.log(value.value_new); // You'll have the string that you want
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you would want to do that or what you would do with the result, but I think the RegEx you want is:

```
var asString = '{"apiunits":{"amount":"0"},"total":{"requests":"10","results":"10"},"project":{"projects":"1"}};'

//Replace either curly with a space. Note in RegEx you have to escape the curly braces with a backslash
var replaced = asString.replace(/\{|\}/gi, ' ');

console.log(replaced);
//outputs -->" "apiunits": "amount":"0" ,"total": "requests":"10","results":"10" ,"project": "projects":"1"  ;"
```

In my example, I'm using the pipe for "or" but either of your previous attempts would work if the curly braces were escaped:

```
value = value.replace("/[\{\}]/g", " ");
```

or

```
 value = value.replace("/\{/g", " ");
 value = value.replace("/\}/g", " ");
```